# Image gallery that scrolls to the image that corresponding to the clicked thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am creating a website that has an image gallery.

You have a side menu with the different categories, a hidden div that appears when you click on a category, filled with thumbnails, and when you click on any of the thumbnails it hides the thumbnails div and shows the image gallery in its place.

An example of what I am trying to do is here : http://www.matitacorp.com/web/portfolio.php

What I would like to do is when the thumbnail div hides and the image gallery appears I would also like the image that corresponds to the thumbnail clicked to appear, even if it is 3 or 4 pictures lower in the scrollable thumbnail gallery.

I've tried using .scrolltop() and setting the value but I think that I am missing something. My div's appear properly but I am not getting the scrolltop value to work or I am using the complete wrong function. Hopefully someone can help out.

Here is a piece of the code that I am trying to use:

```
//thumbnail section
<div id="booth">      
  <a href="#" id="identityoverlay"><img src="thumb1" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="#" id="identityoverlayA"><img src="thumb2" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="#" id="identityoverlayB"><img src="thumb3" alt="" /></a>
</div>

//main image section
<div id="identityOverlay" style="background-image:url(images/bkgrnd_700.gif); height:720px; display:none;">               

    <div id="imageGallery style="padding-left:95px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:15px; overflow:auto; height:610px;">            
                <img src="mainImg1" /><br />              
                <img src="mainImg2" /><br />              
                <img src="mainImg3" /><br />              
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#identityoverlay").click(function () {
      $("#identityOverlay").show();     
      $("#booth").hide();
});    

    $("#identityoverlayA").click(function () {       
      var myCont = document.getElementById ("imageGallery");
              myCont.scrollTop(100); 

      $("#identityOverlay").show();       
      $("#booth").hide();
});   
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend validating your xhtml first - it's invalid. What's the actual question here?

Comment: I added a snippet of code, yes I see that I missed a quotation mark and isn't in proper HTML format, it was just to show what I have. When you click on a thumbnail in div booth, I have identityOverlay appear (this works), but I also want it to scroll to the right section of identityOverlay depending on the thumbnail that you have clicked on. I don't know how to have the imageGallery div which is inside identityOverlay scroll to the proper section. Is this possible? I read about scrollTop and thought I could set the scrollTop attribute of my div but it is not working.

Comment: Did you read the jquery API manual? Use scrollTo() (basic JS) to scroll to given x/y (or y/x). - What I'm saying is that scrollTop probably does not what you think it does: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have couple problems with your code.

First of all you should prevent default action on click and secondly you should hide/show divs first and then scroll to wanted position.

Here is the modified code:

```
$("#identityoverlayA").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    $("#booth").hide();
    $("#identityOverlay").show();       

    var myCont = document.getElementById ("imageGallery");
    myCont.scrollTop(100); 
});
```